# Xcode won't commit to master branch after Cherry-Picking

Tags: xcode, git

Some days ago I cherry-picked one of my previous commits to see some old code, then I cherry-picked back to my last commit and kept working on a code making some commits. Today I see that all my commits since I cherry-picked back are not present in `master` branch and origin `remote`.

[image]

However, all new commits are present when I click on the project name.

[image]

What should I do to fix this? I want all my commits to be in the `master` branch and `origin` remote.

Edit: `git status` returns:

```
HEAD detached from e8b3dd0
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   mud track.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/hex.xcuserdatad/UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate
    modified:   mud track/Card/NotificationsView.swift
    modified:   mud track/ViewController.swift

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Comment: What does `git status` say?

Comment: @simon-pearson hi! I edited the question adding git status output